# No host specified in URI file

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

Can Anyone help me out with this error
"======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): [No host specified in URI file:///](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb4Hk.png)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2658:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2569:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:89:59)
#3      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:50:14)
#4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey. (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:504:13)>

Comment: show me your image url

Comment: well, what is the value of `key.url`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding **`'http://'`** before your url if you are not doing it .

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this exception since I wasn't using `Uri` correctly.

So instead of passing a string as a `path` parameter to `Uri`:

```
http.post(Uri(path: 'https://example.com/'), 
          headers: <String, String>{}, 
          body: <String, String>{},);
```

you should use `Uri.parse` in order to create a **Uri** from a string:

```
http.post(Uri.parse('https://example.com/'), 
          headers: <String, String>{}, 
          body: <String, String>{},);
```